# How to prepareForSegue using NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

How to prepareForSegue using NSMutableArray?

```
NSMutableArray *theNews;
```

and this is prepareForSegue code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[theNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];


    }
}
```

if i run the code i got this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81c0f40'

Comment: are u getting error on line [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];?

Comment: Apparently theNews is actually a dictionary, not an array. Where did you create that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that data in your `theNews` array is kind of `NSDictionary`. There is no method called `- objectAtIndexPath:` with `NSDictionary`. You should use `– objectForKey:` instead (or some other methods)